# How do I create a legend for a heatmap in Bokeh 12.4.1

Tags: python-3.x, heatmap, bokeh

The recent version of Bokeh allows the programmer to put the legend outside of the chart area. This can be accomplished like described [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html):

```
p = figure(toolbar_location="above")
r0 = p.circle(x, y)

legend = Legend(items=[
    ("sin(x)"   , [r0]),),
], location=(0, -30))

p.add_layout(legend, 'right')
show(p)
```

Note: A legend object is attached to a plot via add_layout. The legend object itself consists of tuples and strings together with glyph lists.

The question is what to do when you are just drawing one "data" series as is the case with the code below, adapted from [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/unemployment.html):

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import figure

col = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
row = ['A', 'B', 'C' , 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 
'N', 'O', 'P']

# this is the colormap from the original NYTimes plot
colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce",     
"#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors)

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict (
    row = test['plate_row'],
    col = test['plate_col'],
    values = test['Melt Temp']
))

TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom"

p = figure(title="Plate Heatmap", x_range = (0.0,25.0), y_range =     
           list(reversed(row)), x_axis_location="above", tools=TOOLS)

r1 = p.rect(x="col", y="row", width=1, height=1,
       source=source, 
       fill_color={'field': 'values', 'transform': mapper},
       line_color=None)

legend = Legend(items=[
    ("test"   , [r1]),
], location=(0, -30))

p.add_layout(legend, 'left')
show(p)      # show the plot
```

The issue here is that there is only one glyph. What I actually need is an explanation of what value range is included for different colors. Clearly, this is possible, because the plots defined [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/heatmap_chart.html) show that it's possible.

Update:

Now that I am writing about the problem, I am starting to think, that perhaps I can can just plot multiple series, one for each color...and only plot those coordinates that fall within a certain range...that seems rather clunky though. So any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching this a bit more, I found 2 ways of creating a legends that show what each color means on the heatmap:

#### 1.) Painting several glyph series:

First, I divide the number range into bins like so:

```
min_value = test['Melt Temp'].min()
max_value = test['Melt Temp'].max()
increment = round((max_value - min_value)/9)
num_bins = [(lower, lower+increment) for lower in 
range(int(floor(min_value)), int(round(max_value)), 
int(round(increment)))]
```

Then, I create sub tables from the main tables like so:

```
source_dict = {}
for range_tuple in num_bins: 
    range_data = test[(test['Melt Temp'] > int(range_tuple[0])) & 
    (test['Melt Temp'] <= int(range_tuple[1]))]
    source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict (
            row = range_data['x'],
            col = range_data['y'],
            values = range_data['Value']))
source_dict[range_tuple] = source
```

Then I zip up the colors with a column data source sub-table:

```
colors = RdYlBu9
glyph_list = []
for color, range_tuple in zip(colors, num_bins):
    r1 = p.rect(x="col", y="row", width=1, height=1,
           source=source_dict[range_tuple], 
           fill_color=color,
           line_color=None)
    glyph_list.append(r1)
```

Lastly, I create an explicit legend object which requires string-glyph-tuples. The legend object then gets attached to the plot:

```
legend_list = [("{0}<={1}".format(bin[0], bin[1]), [glyph]) for bin, 
glyph in zip(num_bins, glyph_list)]
legend = Legend(items=legend_list, location=(0, -50))
p.add_layout(legend, 'left')
show(p)
```

Downsides to this approach:

- It somehow seems a bit clunky.
- Another potential downside I discovered while trying to select objects: If you click on one datapoint of a certain color, all datapoints of that color get selected. Depending on what you want to do this may be a plus or a minus.

#### 2.) Colorbar:

Second approach makes use of @Okonomiyaki's comment above, and is a lot simpler. The basic gist is that you use a color mapper for determining colors of your glyphs. You also create a [ColorBar](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#color-bars) as Okonomiyaki pointed out:

```
mapper = LogColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", low=min_value, 
    high=max_value)
source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict (
        row = test['x'], col = test['y'], values = test['value']))

p = figure(title="Plate Heatmap", x_range = (0.0,25.0), y_range = 
list(reversed(row)),
x_axis_location="above", plot_width=650, plot_height=400)

r1 = p.rect(x="col", y="row", width=1, height=1,
            source=source, 
            fill_color={'field': 'values', 'transform': mapper},
            line_color=None)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, ticker=LogTicker(),
                 label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, 
                 location(0,0))
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'left')
layout = p
show(layout)
```

I like the elegance of this approach. The only downside to this approach is that you don't get a clean range of numbers that define a given color.

If other people come up with even more elegant approaches, please
share!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way through using CategoricalColorMapper and then not creating an explicit legend object. 
There may be a way to create the legend object explicitly with the same layout, I will have a look later.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool,CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Blues8

# values to assign colours on
values = np.arange(100,107)
# values that will appear in the legend!!!
legend_values = ['100-101','101-102','102-103','103-04','104-05','105-06',
                 '106-07']

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict (
    row = np.arange(100,107),
    col = np.arange(100,107),
    values = np.arange(100,107),
    legend_values = legend_values
))
mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=list(values),palette=Blues8)
TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom"

p = figure(title="Plate Heatmap", x_range = (100,107), y_range =     
           [90,107], x_axis_location="above", tools=TOOLS)

r1 = p.rect(x="col", y="row", width=1, height=1,
       source=source, 
       fill_color={'field': 'values', 'transform': mapper},
       line_color=None,legend='legend_values')

p.legend.location = "bottom_right"
show(p)      # show the plot
```

See the image here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lkEW.png)

Comment: In this case, we have 7 categories, and 7 different values. I wonder: How would this scenario deal with the case where the number range spans 0-700 and you have 7 categories. In this case, there would be 700 different values, and only 7 bins. Is there a way to map say 0-100 to bin 1 which is "0-100" etc?

Comment: If you want to just use a colorbar, see this example http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#color-bars. But if it has to be a legend with discrete points referring to the ranges I think you need to then change the values you put into CategoricalColorMapper. I will update the post when i get a change to test it out.

Comment: I am also trying to work on an alternative solution. Looking forward to seeing your solution to it! Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Yea unfortunately looks like if you don't use the colorbar you are forced to re-plot, unless you want to start making hacky code.  I wonder what happens if you made the plot in matplotlib and converted it?

Comment: Again: Thank you for your helpful pointer! It was your help that led me to the solution above!